# PowerShell error 'can't call null-value expresssion'

Tags: powershell

When I run my power shell script, I got the following error:
My question is why I am getting such errorr? char:13 is $ in $results, that is the return value of what I call, why I am getting a 'can't call null-value expression'?

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\test.ps1:79 char:13
+             $results = ($content -match "MyValues" -split "=")[1].Tr ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Is content a string or an array?

Comment: It is easy to get this error in this case when $content is a single string in which case -match returns a boolean. Also when no lines in $content match MyValues.